# Proper Swipe gesture recognizer iOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I haven't been able to find a tutorial on how to properly setup a gesture recognizer for iOS.
I need to detect swipe up & down, and the callbacks for them.

Any help, appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need two recognizers, one for swiping up, and the other for swiping down:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeUpGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUpFrom:)];
swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
```

and for the handler:

```
- (void)handleSwipeUpFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

}
```

Finally, you add it to your view:

```
[view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGestureRecognizer];
```

The same for the other direction (just change all the `Up`s to `Down`s).

Comment: You are right: I was too focused on thinking that the main point for swipe recognizers is having one recognizer for direction... I added that step...

Comment: I never setup a view.. what can i put as default view or current view?
also do i put all this in init method?

Comment: (I want it applied to the whole iPhone screen)

Comment: Then add it to: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window`; since you say you do not have a view, I guess the place where to put this code is your appDidFinishLaunching... the usual place would be a `viewDidLoad` inside a view controller...

Comment: Nah, that view's not working. I was thinking more along the lines of `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view]` or self but that doesnt work either.

Comment: did not get you were using Cocos2D. Use: `[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView addGestureRecognizer:...`; This is what I happen to use and it works.

Comment: Okay i got it. `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGestureRecognizer];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16688/discussion-between-david-and-sergio)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Xcode 7.3. , Swift 2.2.

```
import UIKit

class Viewcontroller: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createAndAddSwipeGesture()
    }

    private func createAndAddSwipeGesture()
    {
        let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Viewcontroller.handleSwipeLeft(_:)))
        swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }

    @IBAction func handleSwipeLeft(recognizer:UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print(" Handle swipe left...")

    }
}
```